# how to pass database connection properties dynamically to connect to different database in pentaho

Tags: kettle

I'm using kettle transformation to store CSV files data to database.My client requirement is to store the same CSV files into different databases(eg:Oracle and postgres) dynamically.How to achieve this ?I have tried with kettle Job and set variables method.It doesn't worked for me. How to pass the database connection properties dynamically to the transformation as parameter to connect to different databases.Please help me out for this issue.

Answer (score 5):

To connect to different databases of the SAME type, you can just set the relevant properties (host, port, database name, schema, username, password and whatever the connection requires).

However, if your database types change, you need to set up a Generic Database connection, where you need to provide the class of the JDBC driver, the full connection URL (including parameters), the username and password.

By changing those variables you can switch your target database.

Bear in mind that a variable cannot be set and used in the same transformation. Due to the parallel nature of transformation steps you need to set the variable values in a Transformation 1 then use them in a Transformation B and enclose both transformations inside a parent job. Best variable scope is "valid within root job".

Comment: if the answer is correct you should accept it as such. And it's only polite to upvote it.

Comment: How do you approach the Generic Database Connection? How do you do that? Could you give more details? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

actually, for different databases using multiple shared.xml files in multiple KETTLE_HOME locations may work just fine, I didn't have time to test thoroughly but I do use KETTLE_HOME and shared.xml for one-off runs, the databases are the same though, at lease as per connection.type.